# pod install YelpAPI producing error

Tags: ios, swift, api, cocoapods, yelp

I have setup CocoaPods in my project and successfully installed AFNetworking so I know I am good there...

When I try to install 'YelpAPI', I receive this error in my terminal...

[!] The platform of the target `ForTheTroops` (iOS 9.3) is not compatible with `YelpAPI (1.0.3)`, which does not support `ios`.

I can't seem to figure out why and I can't find any instructions to set this up properly... even in Yelp's developer site.

Here's a screenshot of my podfile as well.

[Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JayMY.png)

Comment: " platform :ios, '8.0' " copy it and paste it under " use_frameworks! "  and try it again hope it work.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help. It appears that the yelp api is only available for OS X now.

Comment: Have you tried with `pod 'YelpAPI', '~> 2.0'` ?

Comment: do you need "YelpAPI Phone Search API" ??

Comment: I have tried the 'YelpAPI', '~> 2.0' idea. no change.

I wanted to use there places data within a project. I wanted to find nearby places and do stuff with them in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I worked with Yelp on this and the Podspec file was updated.

Pod 'YelpAPI' works successfully now for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You're writing `pod "YelpApi"` which is wrong. You should write `pod 'YelpApi'`. Notice the " " and ' ' which I've changed.

Edit: It is not available for iOS at all. It's only for OS X.

Comment: Good call... I made the ' ' change but I received the same error when doing a pod install.

[!] The platform of the target `ForTheTroops` (iOS 8.0) is not compatible with `YelpAPI (1.0.3)`, which does not support `ios`.

Comment: I gave it another try with your edits... still no luck. I've updated the Podfile in my question to reflect the changes. I'm still receiving that same error.

Comment: Try updating the CocoaPods. And retry. Run `sudo gem update` to update cocoapods.

Comment: Check it out. Not available for iOS. It's only for OS X. That's what `The platform of the target ForTheTroops (iOS 9.3) is not compatible with YelpAPI (1.0.3), which does not support ios.` means.

Comment: Yup... you are correct. Thanks for helping to clarify that. It was tripping me up since it said it would work for Obj-C and Swift so I only assumed that meant, iOS, but it does not and it only works for OS X right now.  Thanks again for your help in clarifying this!

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

The current podspec can be seen [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/YelpAPI/1.0.3/YelpAPI.podspec.json) or by doing a `cat $(pod spec which yelpapi)` in the terminal.

You can see under `platforms` that the podspec only supports `OSX` and not `iOS`.

Comment: Thanks Idr!  I've added an issue to their GitHub in hopes of a resolution. I might go with the Google Places API route instead for now to gain local business info instead.  Thanks again for reaching out!